# Having trouble with file i/o in C. Not sure about fgetc() or getc() or when to use i++

Tags: html, c

I'm trying to write a small program to sort the colors in a 16 x 16 html table. I already wrote a program to print the table with random color values. That worked fine. But I seem to be having trouble with fgetc() and i++. Kind of embarrassing. I decided to focus on printing the color values themselves to the console as a test of the program code. I can't get it to work. Here's the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char chr = '\0';
    char ch[15504];
    char clrstr[7];
    int i = 0;

    FILE *out_file = fopen("colors.html", "r");

    if(out_file != NULL)
    {
        while(ch[i] = fgetc(out_file) != EOF)
        {
            if (ch[i] == '<')
                i++;
            if (ch[i] == 't')
                i++;
            if (ch[i] == 'd')
            {
                i++;

                while(ch[i] != '\n')
                {
                    if(ch[i] == '#')
                    {
                        i++;

                        while(ch[i] != '"')
                        {
                            clrstr[chr] = ch[i];
                            i++;
                        }

                        for(chr = 0; chr < 7; chr++)
                            putchar(clrstr[chr]);

                        printf("\n");
                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }

            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}
```

As I said, I gave up on the sorting algorithm for a while. I decided to focus on the output. I may use a file or the console. It's written with putchar() right now, so the console is the interest. I need help producing the right color values. I'll attach the html page as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>
 Random Colors
 </title>
 <style>
 body {
     background-color:#000000;
     font-family:"Arial";
 }
 h1 {
     color:#FFFFFF;
     text-align:center;
 }
 table {
    margin:auto;
 }
 td {
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>

 <h1>Random Colors</h1>

 <table border="1">
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#C14E39">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1902E6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#63B9B1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9EC7CB">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#76CDE4">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8D23E7">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3F6BB3">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F589DA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#56CB4D">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#A9D3B5">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#A02EBC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#D680E0">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#DE6292">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#24FDC9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4B0604">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#21B270">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#B1D126">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#29A0AF">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0C9D29">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#09595E">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F3C9A2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#E64F67">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F36ECD">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F9F197">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#CDE1D1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0D6226">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#727AF4">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9B3C98">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#CE43E2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#44F454">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#22F5E9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#D03FC4">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#965F38">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B705AD">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#FE4718">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#ED1400">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3B755B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#A208F2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#E51E44">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4A6859">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F69E36">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#AA7487">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#6A6870">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#84ED1B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#35B2E9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8354C5">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#055BE8">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9A77D9">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#D920D6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#59A948">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B14018">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#C1815A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#C77B96">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5AD51F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9E01B1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5267A8">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#397AF4">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#188051">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#EE61C9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#19EC01">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#BC252F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#6A8574">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#6A9299">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F61328">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#02ED9A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#69F426">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#ED1E9F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0E18C3">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1F32BD">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#554F47">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#75918B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#C866EC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2EED83">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B00F1B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#87EC65">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#E2E0D3">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#CB162B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#700F0A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#BA5264">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5C6B38">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#A9FDEA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8F8DB1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#D94B26">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4A40D3">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#BB3366">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3CCE01">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#14563C">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#05FDAE">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4D8F7A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#29794D">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#CD81CC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#684307">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#DA0C57">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1D79DE">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8D01E0">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#551791">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#25F84F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#11CE60">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3F3F34">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#EFA303">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#13F5FA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#75EAE5">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#E1D76A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#909465">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1DC942">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#DB667F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#18B868">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#228B18">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#717049">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#D92D88">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4B2996">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#587FAC">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#0F5750">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B94DDC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#658153">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#85B7D9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#CEF010">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#AA2B4B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#757C7F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#01B2BA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#071364">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3F5E0A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#00FAEF">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#89318B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#17E96A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4DC181">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8C31EE">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#FD3AF0">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#DF9077">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#DF837C">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#E499F9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#82E5C0">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#46BD22">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#23F8BC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#48DDE1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B0E1F3">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#931366">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#ECB885">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0CCE9B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#14DDEA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#45DF42">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#C0AE50">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B7B260">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#ADB116">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#1D2E2A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#E9E8C8">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#440FAF">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#80C55D">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#01B2A6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#96DBCF">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#C25249">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3697BA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5933B0">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5A1D88">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#A5AD22">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5BD79C">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#83CA59">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#FA7B7D">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#652284">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#DF7C64">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#41A6F3">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#811449">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0C3BED">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F6DF0A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#987935">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5D6ADC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8B940E">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0A5D87">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#C1FAEC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#01E56C">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#541EFD">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#C6B729">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#493326">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#449260">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1E0CD2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2B0384">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#C38267">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2E7E75">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#96C62B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5D8A6E">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#627A27">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#00FE8C">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#FAFBCA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B49AD0">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#52D160">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#7AB8C8">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#AEA983">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#FE142A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0FB133">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2589A2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3AD5C1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#09EDDE">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#4A49E1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#499FD7">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8828F1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2C50D1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#094C24">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#153F36">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#A81DD3">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#ADE81F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#955FC5">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2CFE04">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0EB66E">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4A47F6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5CACF6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#35D9BA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4127EA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F284F8">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#2F74F8">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#69EFE4">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4BC7C6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#EBD7EC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#E34783">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#067482">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1D64D2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#7CCDEB">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#F2FC74">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#903FC9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1BDE14">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#52F825">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B99DE8">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#EC0A11">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#EA59A5">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#7D7E5C">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#EA7933">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#06F626">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#674D23">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#128826">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9A13FE">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#5A66E9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B1674F">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#89A2BD">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#014002">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#4DF27E">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2C980E">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#8F8F40">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9F1B90">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#B3844D">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#6E039A">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#032471">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#23D3FC">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#A83C14">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#541190">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3ADA07">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9419DB">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#7A6EC2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#0C9F92">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#7D0F0C">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#3AA4FA">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#BBA09B">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#DA5CC4">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#7874CE">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#838E88">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#21EED8">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#759E31">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#2B2EC0">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You read a character, `ch[i] = fgetc(out_file)` and then you check what it was, `if (ch[i] == '<') i++;` but then you go and check what the _next_ character is in `if (ch[i] == 't')`. How's that going to work? You haven't read the next character yet. Also, you should be `fgetc` into an `INT` to safely compare with `EOF`

Comment: And `while(ch[i] = fgetc(out_file) != EOF)` should be `while((ch[i] = fgetc(out_file)) != EOF)` (as well as reading into an `int` variable first, as Ted mentions).

Comment: This code really wants a switch statement to enhance your clarity and control, imo.  Sample of  [your adapted code here](https://godbolt.org/z/WjoncKs3d)

Comment: You could also simplify it by reading the whole file into memory. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/fahPTTWEa)

Comment: Once you execute an `i++`, the expression `ch[i]` no longer refers to the character you most recently read.  Nor, of course, does it refer to any character that you haven't read yet, but you seem to be assuming that it does.

Comment: I am unsure what the point of including a lengthy HTML file is. If it is supposed to demonstrate the desired output, or show the input, then a 3x2 table would be good for a **minimal example**.

Comment: @jbenari, Why 15504?

Comment: Hey. That number is the number of lines in the html file times the number of characters in the longest line. I thought that was a safe number for the array. Maybe too generous. I don't know. Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when compiling your code, the compiler gave a warning about needing additional parentheses around the "while" loop test while reading your file.

```
while(ch[i] = fgetc(out_file) != EOF)

/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/HTML_Colors/main.c|14|warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]|
```

After adding an additional parentheses pair per the warning suggestion, I then tested out the code.

In testing out your code and doing some debugging, the short answer is that you are attempting to analyze the full file data within the "ch" character array before you actually have the whole file read into the array.  Your code is reading a character, then attempting to read past the current point of character population, which produced undefined behavior and ultimately segmentation faults.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/HTML_Colors/bin/Release$ ./HTML_Colors 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Basically, this is the start of your point of contention.

```
        while((ch[i] = fgetc(out_file)) != EOF)
        {
            if (ch[i] == '<')
                i++;
            if (ch[i] == 't')
                i++;
            if (ch[i] == 'd')
```

What needed to be done was for the entire file being read and stored into the "ch" character array, and then analyze the data within the character array.  With that, following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char chr = '\0';
    char ch[15504];
    char clrstr[7];
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 15504; i++)
        ch[i] = '\0';

    i = 0;

    FILE *out_file = fopen("colors.html", "r");

    if(out_file != NULL)
    {
        while((ch[i] = fgetc(out_file)) != EOF)     /* Read the file and store all of the character information right away*/
            i++;

        count = i + 1;
        i = 0;

        while (i < count)                           /* Now loop through the character array */
        {
            if ((ch[i] == '<') && (ch[i+1] == 't') && (ch[i+2] == 'd'))     /* To avoid picking up td CSS info */
            {
                i += 3;

                while(ch[i] != '\n')
                {
                    if(ch[i] == '#')
                    {
                        chr = 0;
                        clrstr[7] = '\0';
                        i++;

                        while(ch[i] != '"')
                        {
                            clrstr[chr] = ch[i];
                            chr++;
                            i++;
                        }

                        for(chr = 0; chr < 7; chr++)
                            putchar(clrstr[chr]);

                        printf("\n");
                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }

            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Following are the key points.

- Just to be neat, the entire "ch" character array is initialized with the terminator character.
- Next, the file is read and stored, character by character into the "ch" character array.
- Then, starting from the beginning of the populated array, the data is analyzed to identify "<td>" records containing the color attributes.
- To omit the inclusion of the CSS "td" style definition, the "if" test chain was refined to trigger testing on the consecutive characters "<td".

  td {
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  }

With those bits of refactoring, following was the first few lines of sample output compared with the data in the html document.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/HTML_Colors/bin/Release$ ./HTML_Colors 
C14E39
1902E6
63B9B1
9EC7CB

<tr>
 <td style="background-color:#C14E39">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#1902E6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#63B9B1">&nbsp;</td>
 <td style="background-color:#9EC7CB">&nbsp;</td>
```

Give that a try to see if it fulfills your requirements.

The biggest take-aways from this issue would be, first check the compiler output for warnings to see if some type of code refinement is necessary, and reference some proper "C" and "IDE" tutorials on how to debug programs, as that would probably quickly alerted you to what was going wrong with the logic.

Comment: That was an awesome answer. Thank you so much. I've heard C programming can be really scary. I'll try not to worry. I'm sure I'll learn a lot from this experience. And this website. But I'll try not to ask to many questions. Peace.